# Thinking Problem Involving Average Rate of Change

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Here is the question: Suppose that the number of houses in a new subdivision after t months of development is modelled by $N(t)=\frac{100t^3}{100}+t^3$. where $N$ is the number of houses and $0\leq t\leq 12$.

-Calculate the average rate of change in the number of houses built over the first 6 months

***Here is what I think I have to do:***

First I think I need to substitute 6 in for t and solve for the number of houses.  Then after I need to use the average rate of change formula $\frac{\Delta N(t)}{\Delta t} =  \frac{N(t_2)-N(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}$ 
and use the interval given.  So 12 would be my $t_2$ and 0 would be my $t_1$.

Let me know if I have any errors here please, and if so please help me get back on the right track :).  I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Your avg. rate of change formula gives the average rate between times $t_1$ and $t_2$. Over what time period do you think you want to calculate the average?

Comment: Why did you pick $t_1=0$ and $t_2=12$? How do those numbers relate to question? 

Most of the other things you are doing look good!

Comment: In your definition of $N$, $N= 2*t^3$. Your delta between periods would be $(t+1)^3 - t^3$. Is the definition of $N$ correct?

Comment: @DannyDan This is how we have been taught in class, so there shouldn't be an error with with the definition of N or the formula.

Comment: @Ash, it is simple reduction $100t^3/100 = t^3$...

Comment: @DannyDan yes but that doesn't answer my question.  I just wanted to know if I am making the right approach.  Is substituting the 6 in for "t" in $N(t)=100(t^3)/100 + t^3$ all that has to be done? Because for calculating the average rate of change you use the deltaN(t)/delta(t)=N(t2)-N(t1)/t2-t1 .

Comment: @cuddlyCuttlefish So with this instead wouldn't the interval for time in months now become between 0 and 6? So t2=6 and t1=0

Comment: Yes! You would want $t_1=0$ and $t_2=6$, because you want the average from month 0 through month 6.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish Great! Then I am on the right track now then.  Thanks for the help.  By the way, I love your profile name.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish so after these calculations I ended up with approximately 68.  Though I am wondering if I made a calculation error somewhere.  When evaluating I ended up with $deltaN(t)/delta(t)=100(216)/100 + 216 - [100(0)/100 + 0]$  I was trying to follow order of operations and became unsure if whether or not the 100 should cancel out first or if you go ahead with multiplying through the brackets; which is what I did to get 68.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish Attempting it the other way results with 1, which I do not think really makes sense.  Actually, now that I look at it 0/0 is undefined so this could not work anyway

Comment: The 100s do cancel; if you do it that way, the answer is $88.\bar6$.

($\frac{N(6) - N(0)}{6-0}= \frac{216+216-0-0}{6} = \frac{532}{6} = 88.\bar6$).

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish Oh oops, i forgot about it being all divided by t2-t1

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish where did the 216 +216 come from? Because when the 100 cancels, shouldn't it still be 216/216? Why did the division cancel?

Comment: Is the question $\frac{100t^3}{100+t^3}$ or $\frac{100t^3}{100} + t^3$? I assumed the latter, though you would $not$ cancel the 100 if it is the first case.